# Dplyr Mutate missing group score when one observation is NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to calculate a certain variable for each country-year in my data. However, if there is one value missing, the entire country-year gets NA for this variable.

How can I rewrite the code to for these cases base the calculation on the available data?

This is example data:

```
aus96 <- data.frame(country = c("AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", 
                                "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL",
                                "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", 
                                "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL"),
                    party = c("Social", "Labor", "Democrats", "Liberal", "National",
                              "Social", "Labor", "Democrats", "Liberal", "National",
                              "Social", "Labor", "Democrats", "Liberal", "National",
                              "Social", "Labor", "Democrats", "Liberal", "National"),
                    lr = c(3.84, 4.33, 4.69, 6.45, 6.5,
                           4.84, 3.33, 2.69, 3.45, 10.5,
                           3.84, 4.33, NA, 6.45, 46.5,
                           4.84, 3.33, 2.69, 3.45, 1.5),
                    share = c(1.7, 38.7, 6.7, 38.6, 8.2,
                              5.7, 20.7, 26.7, 8.6, 8.2,
                              4.7, 28.7, 0, 40.6, 9.2,
                              1.7, 28.7, 16.7, 9.6, 18.2),
                    year = c(1,1,1,1,1,
                             1,1,1,1,1,
                             2,2,2,2,2,
                             2,2,2,2,2))
```

```
aus96 %>% group_by(country, year) %>% 
  mutate(polarization = sqrt(sum((((lr-sum(((lr * share)/sum(share))))/5)^2)*share)))
```

But this gives me:

```
country party        lr share  year polarization
<chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
AU      Social     3.84   1.7     1         2.04
AU      Labor      4.33  38.7     1         2.04
AU      Democrats  4.69   6.7     1         2.04
AU      Liberal    6.45  38.6     1         2.04
AU      National   6.5    8.2     1         2.04
NL      Social     4.84   5.7     1         4.04
NL      Labor      3.33  20.7     1         4.04
NL      Democrats  2.69  26.7     1         4.04
NL      Liberal    3.45   8.6     1         4.04
NL      National  10.5    8.2     1         4.04
AU      Social     3.84   4.7     2        NA   
AU      Labor      4.33  28.7     2        NA   
AU      Democrats NA      0       2        NA   
AU      Liberal    6.45  40.6     2        NA   
AU      National  46.5    9.2     2        NA   
NL      Social     4.84   1.7     2         1.42
NL      Labor      3.33  28.7     2         1.42
NL      Democrats  2.69  16.7     2         1.42
NL      Liberal    3.45   9.6     2         1.42
NL      National   1.5   18.2     2         1.42
```

I need a value for each observation in country `AU` year `2`, including for the party `Democrats` that has a missing score `lr` on which the new variable is based. Any help is much appreciated! Many thanks

Comment: Yes, that is correct, because `NA` could be anything and therefore the result of your formula could be anything. You need to decide how the `NA` should be interpreted, before asking R to compute. E.g. would it make sense to set it to 0, or to the mean (or median) of the other values, etc... However, everything you would do would disguise the true result: `NA` - We don't know, and we made a reasonable guess.

Comment: For this specific case you might just want to remove Democrats from (AU,2) group, for this you can add `na.rm=TRUE` to sum calls that deal with `lr`, you can check `?sum`for details.  Sepcific filter or replacement of NA values might be more robust for full dataset though.